# Convert string of words to unique number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building my own custom speller that should correct word or number of words to custom correction.

For that I created a SQL table that have the next structure:

```
|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|
|      id (int11)     |  keyword (varchar 255)  |  correction (varchar 255)  |
|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|
|          1          |        Facebooc         |          Facebook          |
|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|
|          2          |       I lovi you        |         I love you         |
|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|
|          3          |     This is a tsst      |        This is a test      |
|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------|
```

- Keyword column is mark as unique and have index on it (asc)
- keyword can be more than one word (batch of words)
- When I get request with new keyword, my code is making a select query to check if this specific keyword have a correction (if keyword not exists its inserting the new keyword to the table without correction.

Now I expect this table to be very large (about 10 million rows and even more), so I thought maybe placing a unique flag and index on the keyword column is not so good idea.

1. Does the correct structure is good for my needs?
2. I thought maybe to add another int column to the table and check if there a way to convert each keyword to a unique number so maybe it will be easy to search and select data? think its good idea?

Comment: Why do you think "_placing a unique flag and index on the keyword column is not so good idea_"? "_to add another int column to the table_" You mean like an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a column with a short checksum as provided by the [crc32()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.crc32.php) function.
However, crc32() does not generate a unique index. There is a probability greater than 0 that 2 strings generate the same checksum.

If the same checksum is not found for a new keyword, the keyword is certainly not yet in the database.

If the same checksums are found, then the keywords themselves have to be checked.

Whether this method brings advantages in speed also depends heavily on the performance of the database system.